# The memory of Bitmap decode

Tags: android, bitmap

I have some questions about Bitmap decode.

1. When I try to decode Bitmap from a byte[] array, using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray, what is the difference between the param byte[] and the mBuffer byte[] in result bitmap. when the function return will the bitmap still hold reference to the byte[] param?
2. when I decode bitmap from a jpg file from sdcard using the following code:

   ```
   File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "large.jpg");
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
   if(mImageView != null){
       mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   }
   ```

   This jpg file has 10800*5400 resolution and 13.82M size, the result bitmap is not null, and there is no OOM error , but  the bitmap not showing. How could that be ?  I think in this case android should throw an OOM error so that I can catch it to try down scale the bitmap again. But it just shows nothing. It seems unreasonable. Does any know the reason?

Comment: "what is the difference between the param byte[] and the mBuffer byte[] in result bitmap" -- the first one will hold something that is in PNG, JPEG, etc. format. The second one holds AARRGGBB bytes of the decoded image.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I found that when I set the layerType to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, the bitmap will show. So I believe there is a image size limit for hardware renderer.